# is there any fibration $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{S}^n$?

Tags: fibration, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

It is probably a trivial question. But I don't see the answer.

Is there any Hurewicz fibration $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{S}^n$ ?

Is there any fibration $X\to \mathbb{S}^n$, when $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n $?

I appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, certainly there is when $n=1$... 

Comment: What conditions do you want to place on $X$? Open/closed submanifold?

Comment: My approach would be similar to Dylan's: If such a fibration existed for $n>1$, the fibre would be a closed subset $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the weak homotopy type of $\Omega S^n$, and would therefore have nonzero (co)homology in arbitrarily high degrees. In some sense you have an infinite dimensional space embedded in a finite dimensional Euclidean space, which feels wrong. I can't right now see how to rule it out though.

Comment: Whoops- I was being silly. Mark has it right!

Comment: Along this line, it's worth mentioning that Barratt-Milnor constructed examples (higher analogues of the Hawaiian earrings) that embed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but have cohomology in arbitrarily high degrees.  User BS discussed them here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4478/torsion-in-homology-or-fundamental-group-of-subsets-of-euclidean-3-space/31738#31738

Comment: However, $\Omega S^n$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex, and therefore (iirc?) its singular homology is the same as its \check{C}ech homology!

Comment: (... CW complex of finite type... )

Comment: A small note, the answer to the first question is clearly no for $n=2$ by the classification of non-compact $2$-manifolds + Mark's comment.  I imagine there's a reasonable proof the answer is always no for $n>1$ but off the top of my head I'm not seeing it. 

Comment: Doesn't it follow from what "some guy on the street" said? $\Omega S^n$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex of finite type. If it could be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a closed submanifold (take a smooth approximation to the fibration in question and look at the preimage of a regular value), then the dimension of the manifold must be $n-1$. On the other hand, Cech cohomology of manifolds of dimension $n-1$ vanishes above $n-1$, which isn't the case here since Cech cohomology agrees with usual cohomology in this case.

Comment: @Dylan: how do you guarantee the smooth approximation is a fibration?  In the space of maps $Map(A,B)$, fibrations are not an open subspace, in general. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: The following simplifies the original answer (which unnecessarily used singular cohomology).

If $f:\Bbb R^n\to S^n$ is a fibration, then as Mark noted, a fiber $F$ of $f$ is *weak* homotopy equivalent to $\Omega S^n$ (using the 5-lemma, see Prop. 4.66 in Hatcher). I claim that $F$ is in fact homotopy equivalent to $\Omega S^n$.

Indeed, $F$ is homotopy equivalent to the corresponding homotopy fiber of $f$ (Prop. 4.65 in Hatcher). The homotopy fiber consists of pairs $(x,p)$ where $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $p$ is a path in $S^n$ connecting $f(x)$ and the basepoint. It is homotopy equivalent to the space $X$ of maps $[0,1]\to MC(f)$ (the mapping cylinder) sending $0$ into $\Bbb R^n$ and $1$ into the basepoint of $S^n$. Milnor showed that $X$ and $\Omega S^n$ are homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes. Hence, being weak homotopy equivalent to each other, by Whitehead's theorem they are homotopy equivalent to each other.

Now $F$ is finite-dimensional, so its Cech cohomology is eventually zero. Cech cohomology is a homotopy invariant, so we get that the cohomology of $\Omega S^n$ is eventually zero,
contradicting Mark's comment. (It does not matter which cohomology of $\Omega S^n$, they are all isomorphic since $\Omega S^n$ is homotopically a CW-complex.)

Comment: Hi Sergey, when you say that $F$ is finite-dimensional, are you talking about its covering dimension (I see no reason why $F$ should be something nice like a manifold or complex)? Do closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ necessarily have covering dimension less than or equal to $n$? 

Comment: Mark, yes, $F$ is of covering dimension $\le n$, that is, every open cover of $F$ can be refined by a cover whose nerve is of dimension $\le n$. Indeed, by the definition of subspace topology, every open cover of $F$ is the intersection with $F$ of an open cover of an open neighborhood of $F$; hence also of an open cover $C$ of $\Bbb R^n$. This $C$ has a refinement $D$ with a nerve $N$ of dimension $\le n$ since $\Bbb R^n$ is $n$-dimensional (see nice pictures at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension). Finally, the nerve of $D$ intersected with $F$ is a subcomplex of $N$.

Comment: I should add that perhaps some confusion arises from Tyler Lawson's remark that the Barratt-Milnor examples of a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ "have cohomology in arbitrarily high degrees". This is true only of *singular* cohomology, which is not a geometrically interesting cohomology theory, in particular because it is not Brown representable (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47544). 

Comment: Assume that $ p: E\to B $ is a fibration and $ E $ is contractible. We have that the homotopy fiber is homotopy equivalent to the fiber.
But the homotopy fiber is the pullback of $ p: E\to B $ along $ v_0: PB\to B $. Since $ v_ 0 $ is a fibration, the homotopy fiber is, indeed, the homotopy pullback. Hence, the pullback of $ \ast\to B $ along $ v_0 $ is homotopy equivalent to the homotopy fiber (since $ E $ is contractible). This new pullback is $ \Omega B $. So, in general, if $ p: E\to B $ is a fibration with contractible total space, the fiber is homotopy equivalent to $ \Omega B $.

Comment: This makes it much simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a pretty simple answer, patching together everything that's been said in the comments.

By Mark's answer, the fibers have $H_{n-1}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.  And if $n>1$ these fibers are connected.  Alexander duality tells you the Cech cohomology of the fiber in dimension $n-1$ is isomorphic to the reduced $0$-dimensional homology of the complement of the fiber in $\mathbb R^n$.  And some guy on the street's comment tells you that Cech cohomology is regular cohomology.

So this is saying that the fibers separate $\mathbb R^n$, but since the base is $S^n$ with $n \geq 2$, that's impossible.

Comment: Ryan, I'm not getting this. Mark has a *weak* homotopy equivalence. Cech cohomology is not an invariant of weak equivalence. 

Comment: Since $\Omega S^n$ is a CW-space and so is the fiber, then the weak equivalence is an actual equivalence.

Comment: Alternatively, the map induces an isomorphism on singular cohomology (since it's a weak equivalence) and hence on Cech cohomology (since they're both nice CW-complexes).

Comment: Dylan, the fiber is not a CW complex: the original fibration is not assumed PL or smooth.

Comment: Whoops, you're absolutely right...

Comment: @Sergey: as you've pointed out in your answer, the weak equivalence can be made into a homotopy equivalence.  Sorry I abandoned the question -- my calculus class had an exam and I had to run out of the room.  Your answer is the more complete so I'd like to suggest Fernando accept yours. 

Comment: Ryan, thanks. I'm still a bit puzzled by your comment on the $n=2$ case, can you do this case without using Milnor's theorem on functional spaces? In this connection the following example is worth mentioning. The pseudo-arc is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^2$ which does not have any nontrivial paths in it. So it is weakly equivalent to a discrete set of cardinality continuum (which I guess can be seen as CW-complex), but is not homotopy equivalent to any CW-complex.